# Interacting classes in Java. How much interaction is possible?

Tags: java, class, attributes, object-oriented-analysis

I am new to java programming and know it is possible to have class as an attribute as another.

For instance you could have publisher as one class and strategyGame as another. Is there a way to  have it so a method in publisher class that counts the amount of strategyGame objects there is, therefore ability to  display the amount of strategy games that publisher has published?

Thank you

Comment: yes... You keep track of the [Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) you create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple Snippet to keep you going..

Image you have `StrategyGame` class

```
public class StrategyGame {
    private String name;

    public StrategyGame(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    } 
}
```

And inside your `Publisher` class you keep a List of `StrategyGame` objects

```
public class Publisher {

    List<StrategyGame> games;

    public Publisher() {
        games = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void publishGame(String name) {
        games.add(new StrategyGame(name));
    }

    public int getHowManyGamesCreated() {
         return games.size();
    }

}
```

Now how to use it in your `main`?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Publisher publisher = new Publisher();
    publisher.publishGame("Pacman");
    publisher.publishGame("Asteroids");
    System.out.println(publisher.getHowManyGamesCreated());
}
```

Comment: That you, that makes perfect sense. It did not notify me of your answer so sorry for the late reply. It is a lot simpler than I thought. Thank you.